# Not able to populate dropdown with php array

Tags: php, html

Hi I am not able to populate my dropdown with the PHP array. I have referred to many issues like this on this website but its not solving my problem.Please Help me.
This is my code.

```
 <?php
       $arrayNum = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
       echo '<select name="revNumber">';
       foreach($arrayNum as $rev){
       //print_r($rev);die(); when using die(); This line is getting printed. 
           echo '<option value="'.$rev .'">'.$rev.'</option>';  
           }
       echo'</select>';
    ?>
```

and the output which i am getting is:

> > '; foreach($arrayNum as $rev){ //print_r($rev);die(); when using
> >     die(); '.$rev.'  This line is getting printed. echo ''; } echo''; ?>

Comment: where is the closing bracket for `foreach`?

Comment: i closed the loop...i was not able to copy in this stack overflow editor.

Comment: Please post your full code with HTML also.And don't forgot to close the bracket this time.

Comment: please check this once.

Comment: are you sure you are using `.php` file?

Comment: yes i am using .php extension @Mr.Engineer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php 
      $array1 = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10');
    echo '<select name="revNumber">';
    foreach ($array1 as $revNumber) {
        echo '<option value="' . $revNumber . '">' . $revNumber . '</option>';          
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

2 problems :

1- closing brackets

2-you must put `echo </select>` after foreach loop

Comment: This will close the select tag after the first option. You need to move the closing select tag out of the foreach loop.

Comment: Closing foreach bracket should be before `echo('</select>')`.

Comment: i closed it...it was not able to copy in this stack overflow editor.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use brace in for loop. try this.

```
$array1 = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
echo '<select name="revNumber">';
foreach($array1 as $revNumber)
    echo '<option value="' . $revNumber . '">' . $revNumber .     '</option>';          

echo'</select>';
```

Comment: echo '<option value=' . $revNumber . '>' . $revNumber .     '</option>'; try this inside your for loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the foreach loop.

```
$array1 = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
echo '<select name="revNumber">';
foreach($array1 as $revNumber){ 
    echo '<option value="' . $revNumber . '">' . $revNumber .     '</option>';          
}
echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The only missing thing is the foreach loop closing brackets.

```
<?php
  $array1 = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
  echo '<select name="revNumber">';
  foreach($array1 as $revNumber){
   echo '<option value="' . $revNumber . '">' . $revNumber . '</option>';
  }
  echo'</select>';
?>
```

Edit:
Here is what you get after running the above code:

[image: Code result.]

Comment: Well, closing it means you've got your solution. ;)